# Cross-Origin PostMessage method fails

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, http, cross-domain

(*I have looked all over and found many fixes and documentation, but I am posting this because none of them have worked for me yet.*)

I have 2 MVC4 sites in development.  SSO (which is HTTPS) and Videos (which is HTTP)
(both local host right now)

Videos loads a page with an IFRAME pointing to a page on SSO.  It loads the pages correctly.

The SSO page has this javascript:

```
window.onmessage = function (e) {
    if (e.data == 'hello') {
        alert('It works!');
    }
};
```

The Video Page has this code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="100px" height="100px" id="LbpSsoFrame" src="https://localhost:44301/Sso/InFrame"></iframe>
```

After the page is loaded, I use chrome's console (Chrome V32.0.1700.41 m Aura) and call the following line of code:

```
LbpSsoFrame.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');
```

I get this error:

```
code: 18
message: "Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:46086" from accessing a cross-origin frame."
name: "SecurityError"
stack: "Error: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:46086" from accessing a cross-origin frame.↵    at <anonymous>:2:12↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:603:39)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:562:52)↵    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:481:21)"
```

I have am up in front of a brick wall, and hoping someone else can knows what I am doing wrong or what else needs to be done.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll take a moment to express that I am trying to setup an SSO.  I originally was trying to use JQuery Posts to another site, with CORS headers, and that worked for general communication, but the browsers will not store Cookies from a CORS call.   - Now I am trying to use the IFrame and PostMessage combination to send the outgoing requests that can use the iframe page to store/check for cookies, and then return additional packet information to the site that can be used to identify the user on a service request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo, I found out the issue:  I should not have been calling on LbpSsoFrame as an object.  I'm not sure why though.

This is the code that works:

```
document.getElementById('LbpSsoFrame').contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');
```

This is what I had:

```
LbpSsoFrame.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');
```

With that line fixed, I am getting messages across.

I would have thought that

```
document.getElementById('LbpSsoFrame')
```

and

```
LbpSsoFrame
```

were different ways to call the same thing.  Can anyone explain to me what the difference is?  Both can call post message, but I get an HTTPS/HTTP warning or others when using the object directly.

It works now, but I am still a little lost as to why.

Comment: I determined that document.getElementById is required by some browsers as only some browsers expose tag ID's as immediately available variables.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the issue. The problem is that you cannot really access anything except the `postMessage` of the `contentWindow` from the other origin. My issue was that I was first returning `contentWindow` through a promise, and then calling `postMessage`. But returning `contentWindow` from the promise makes it check other attributes and then exception is thrown.